# How to find games by tag and language in Steam

Tags: steam

I'd like to find games of a particular genre (for the purpose, Hidden Objects) that are in a specific language (for the purpose, spanish), or, if not the audio, the text is.

Is there any way to make that kind of search?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there are advanced search options:

1. Go to `Search the Store` by clicking on the loupe icon:

[image: search the store]

2. In this windows you have several bars on the right side, where you have following search options:

   - `Narrow by tag`: Action, Indie, ..., and `search for more tags`
   - `Show selected types`: Games, DLC, ...
   - `Narrow by number of players`: Single-Player, Multi-Player, ...
   - `Narrow by feature`: Steam Achievements, Controller Support, ...
   - `Narrow by OS`: Windows, Mac OS X, SteamOS + Linux
   - `Narrow by language`: English, Bulgarian, ...

The options you have searched for look like this:

Tag search:

[image: tag search]

Language search:

[image: language search]